# Issue With LINQ and Reference List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I Have following code with LINQ

```
var q = (from web in DataContext.Webs select web);
List<int?> k1 = new List<int?>() { 1, 2 };
List<int?> k2=new List<int?>() { 16, 17 };
            q = q.Where(web => DataContext.WebTechMaps.Any(t => t.WebsiteId == web.WebsiteId && k1.Contains(t.TechId)));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(q.Count());
            k1 = k2;
            q = q.Where(web => DataContext.WebTechMaps.Any(t => t.WebsiteId == web.WebsiteId && k1.Contains(t.TechId)));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(q.Count());
```

Here Is what query it generates.

First Execution of count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Web] AS [t0]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[WebTechMap] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t1].[WebsiteId] = ([t0].[WebsiteId])) AND ([t1].[TechId] IN (@p0, @p1))
    )
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [2]
```

Second Execution of count function

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Web] AS [t0]
WHERE (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[WebTechMap] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t1].[WebsiteId] = ([t0].[WebsiteId])) AND ([t1].[TechId] IN (@p0, @p1))
    )) AND (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[WebTechMap] AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t2].[WebsiteId] = ([t0].[WebsiteId])) AND ([t2].[TechId] IN (@p2, @p3))
    ))
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [17]
-- @p2: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16]
-- @p3: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [17]
```

Please Take a look at the parameters passed to query.

Seems it uses the new referenced object for both Expressions.

Somehow @p0  and @p1 change their old values.
I understand that issue is in Linq it uses new referenced object.

```
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [2]



-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [17]
-- @p2: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16]
-- @p3: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [17]
```

Can someone explain how to use same name of List object but keep the query using correct List's

Desired output is

```
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [2]
-- @p2: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16]
-- @p3: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [17]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: -- p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [2]
-- p2: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16]
-- p3: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [17]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query expression uses `k1`. It uses the *variable* `kl`, and that's what's captured. When you change the value of `k1`, that's effectively changing the meaning of the query. If you don't want the meaning of the query to change, don't change the captured variables! Just use `k2` in your second filter:

```
var q = (from web in DataContext.Webs select web);
List<int?> k1 = new List<int?>() { 1, 2 };
List<int?> k2=new List<int?>() { 16, 17 };
q = q.Where(web => DataContext.WebTechMaps
                              .Any(t => t.WebsiteId == web.WebsiteId && 
                                        k1.Contains(t.TechId)));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(q.Count());
q = q.Where(web => DataContext.WebTechMaps
                              .Any(t => t.WebsiteId == web.WebsiteId &&
                                   k2.Contains(t.TechId)));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(q.Count());
```

Comment: I know that if i use k2 it will work fine i have just make simple demo of the issue!

Comment: My Question is why LINQ is not using the reference and it uses changes object. And how to make Linq to use reference.

Comment: Since your problem is the deferred evaluation of k1 until the IQueryable is executed, maybe you could force the evaluation sooner (q = q.ToList().Where(...) or use a different list (replace k1 with new List<int?>(k1)) instead of passing around references.

Comment: I need to add while with list in foreach loop at that case i cant use k1 and k2

Comment: @user780613: Just use a new variable each time, inside the loop. It's *really* unclear what you're trying to achieve, or why you'd want to reuse the variable. I explained why it's behaving the way it is - it's capturing the *variable* `k1`, not its value.

Comment: if i call ToList() it will be evaluated each time and will reduce performance alot because on first execution it will transfer lot of data to server which i don't need. and next ones will run on web server not on sql server and DB is realy big 20M elements

Comment: @user780613: Yes, shouldn't force execution earlier than you need it. But without showing us what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to help you any further.

Comment: @JonSkeet Using new Variable inside loop  each time solves my issue.
Thanks Jon.
But that behavior of linq seems to incorrect or not intuitive.

Comment: @user780613: It's entirely correct with the way that C# captures variables. If it's unintuitive to you, that simply means you need to study the language more carefully.

Comment: @JonSkeet Capturing Variables at execution time using the name of variable instead of reference object is not intuitive( it hepens only when you use LINQ i never have any issue like that and i am experienced developer) if it's intuitive to you than you are in 1 out of 100 persons for whom using name intead of object is good solution. its not a scripting language and i don't use Relflection

Comment: @user780613: No, it doesn't only happen when you use LINQ. It happens any time you use an anonymous function. It happened in C# 2 when you used anonymous methods, for example.