# List Reference issue (LINQ suspected)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a roster of teaching slots that I am trying to fill with teachers and offsiders (that come from the same list).
If I run the program straight through, all Teachers and Offsiders end up the same, despite them being returned from different methods.
If I pause the program, any Teacher or offsider that is observed being created will be a new, different teacher.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046991/issue-with-linq-and-reference-list) question seems to have something along the same lines, which has led to my suspicion that I am misunderstanding an important part of linq, and when queries are completed, but I don't understand how that can happen even across 2 functions.
The calling code, along with the 2 functions, is below. I appreciate any insight you can provide.

Calling Code:

```
Teacher T = list.GetTeacher(lesson);
lesson.SetTeacher(T);
lesson.Teacher.AddLesson(lesson);
Teacher O = list.GetOffsider(lesson);
lesson.SetOffsider(O);
lesson.Offsider.AddLesson(lesson);
```

GetTeacher:

```
public Teacher GetTeacher(Lesson lesson)
{
    List<Teacher> Eligible = Teachers.Where(t1 => t1.Active && t1.Styles.Any(ts1 => ts1.Style == lesson.Style.Style && ts1.Level >= lesson.Style.Level)).ToList();
    if (Eligible.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Don't have any teachers for that style and/or level");
    List<Teacher> HaventTaught = Eligible.Where(t => !t.DatesTaught.Any(dt => dt.AddDays(21).Day < DateTime.Now.Day)).ToList();
    if (HaventTaught.Count == 0)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return Eligible[r.Next(Eligible.Count)];
    }
    else
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return HaventTaught[r.Next(HaventTaught.Count)];
    }
}
```

GetOffsider:

```
public Teacher GetOffsider(Lesson lesson)
{
    if (lesson.Teacher == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Must assign a Teacher to a lesson before an Offsider");
    }
    List<Teacher> Eligible = Teachers.Where(t2 => t2.Active && t2.Styles.Any(ts2 => ts2.Style == lesson.Style.Style && ts2.Level >= lesson.Style.Level)).ToList();
    //remove conflicts of interest
    Eligible = Eligible.Where(t3 => !t3.Avoid.Any(n2 => n2.Equals(lesson.Teacher.Name)) && !lesson.Teacher.Avoid.Any(n4 => n4.Equals(t3.Name))).ToList();

    if (Eligible.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Don't have any offsiders for that style and/or level");
    List<Teacher> HaventTaught = Eligible.Where(t4 => !t4.DatesTaught.Any(dt2 => dt2.AddDays(21).Day < DateTime.Now.Day)).ToList();
    if (HaventTaught.Count == 0)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return Eligible[r.Next(Eligible.Count)];
    }
    else
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return HaventTaught[r.Next(HaventTaught.Count)];
    }
}
```

Note: Both functions return from the HaventTaught Lists currently.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: This question is so common it is [question #2 in the C# tag wiki FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info).

Comment: @KirkWoll, Yes, it would appear that it is. However, I wasn't quite aware that that was the question I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're creating a new `Random` instance in each call.  If you call this quickly, the Random instances will all get seeded with the same seed, and return the same values each call.

I would recommend moving the `Random` instance into a class level variable, which will cause it to be constructed one time, and provide more "random" values as you call this method multiple times in succession.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I got put in the wrong direction by the question I linked to.